# Referring to sheet by it's variable VBA name in a VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm writing a macro to automate some manual processes. One of them is to assign a `IF-ISNA-VLOOKUP` formula to check an intermediate pivot table. I need to do it in `VBA`.

That's the currently used formula:

```
Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(
ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE)),
0,
VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE))"
```

The pivot table I need to check is declared as a worksheet variable `Wb.WsPivot`, I need to access it through the access formula (referring it by it's variable name) or through VBA code (assigning values to cells instead of a formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string (of the formula) at the points where you want to insert the worksheet name and then use `&` to concatenate the formula strings and the name of the worksheet:

```
Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[Workbook.xlsx]" & WsPivot.Name & "'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[Workbook.xlsx]" & WsPivot.Name & "'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE))"
```

To replace the workbook too:

```
Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[" & Wb.Name & "]" & WsPivot.Name & "'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'[" & Wb.Name & "]" & WsPivot.Name & "'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE))"
```

Comment: Forgot to say, the workbook is also declared as a variable `Wb`

Comment: I tried several combinations like this one:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'"Wb.WsPivot & "'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'"Wb.WsPivot & "'!R1C1:R20C18,2,FALSE))`

Still not working :(

Comment: @ffSAM you need a `&` sign before your variable too! Also I gave already the hint that the workbook name is in `Wb.Name` not in `Wb.WsPivot` so you need both, the `Wb.Name` to replace the `workbook.xlsx` and the `WsPivot.Name` to replace the `Sheet1` (which is already done).

Comment: I ran out of ideas, still having problems at the very begining of the table_array syntax...

Comment: I already tried this way. When pressing enter, it just highlights this part of the formula `RC[-6],'["`

Comment: @ffSAM make sure this is one line (without any line breaks in it). Copy it exactly like it is in my answer.

Comment: @PeH I did, the problem persists :(

Comment: @ffSAM Any error message? Does the line turn red? What happens if you try to run the code? Make sure there is no `On Error Resume Next` line in your code.

Comment: @PeH I'm testing the formula directly in the Excel document. After copying it in N2 cell and pressing enter, it just highlights a part of the formula and does anything else, like waiting for a syntax correction

Comment: @ffSAM This code cannot be used as a formula in a cell anymore because it contains VBA. This is the VBA code to write a formula (not a formula). It is necessary to use it in VBA.

Comment: omg sorry for that. Now it concatenates correctly. However not the good name but I guess this is a VBA problem...